# Upload and display picture

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I have already created ShadowUpload.asp and Upload.asp. 
It works but, I want to display picture that was uploaded but I don't know how to display it

My source code is

```
<!-- #include file="ShadowUpload.asp" -->
<form action="<%=Request.ServerVariables( "Script_Name" )%>?action=1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
Picture Profile: <input type="file" name="file1" value="<%=myPicture%>" /><br />
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

 <img border="0" src="<%=myPicture%>" width="90" height="100">`

<%
Dim objUpload
If Request("action")="1" Then
Set objUpload=New ShadowUpload
If objUpload.GetError<>"" Then

Response.Write("sorry, could not upload: "&objUpload.GetError)
Else  `

        Response.Write("found "&objUpload.FileCount&" files...<br />")
        For x=0 To objUpload.FileCount-1`

            If (objUpload.File(x).ImageWidth>200) Or (objUpload.File(x).ImageHeight>200) Then
                Response.Write("image to big, not saving!")
            Else  
                Call objUpload.File(x).SaveToDisk(Server.MapPath("Uploads"), "")
                Response.Write("file saved successfully!")
            End If
            Response.Write("<hr />")
        Next

    End If
End If


%>
```

Comment: You have to get the relative path of the uploaded file into the variable `myPicture` and use that in the `<img` tag. The <img tag should come after the script part, where you could populate the `myPicture` variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the image for every file uploaded, and only if uploaded successfully:

```
If (objUpload.File(x).ImageWidth>200) Or (objUpload.File(x).ImageHeight>200) Then
    Response.Write("image to big, not saving!")
Else  
    Call objUpload.File(x).SaveToDisk(Server.MapPath("Uploads"), "")
    Response.Write("file saved successfully!")
    Response.Write("<br /><img src=""Uploads/" & objUpload.File(x).FileName & """ height=""50"" />")
End If
```

This will show preview of the uploaded picture, with a set height of 50 pixels.